# How do I render an Emoji API on my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, emoji

I'm a beginner and I'm looking to render emojis from the "emojihub" API on my page for a project. It randomly generates an emoji and sends the data in a JSON object:

```json
{
    "name": "baby, type-6",
    "category": "smileys and people",
    "group": "person",
    "htmlCode": [
        "&#128118;",
        "&#127999;"
    ],
    "unicode": [
        "U+1F476",
        "U+1F3FF"
    ]
}
```

I'm looking to render the generated emoji on my page and the API documentation says to use the htmlCode but I'm having issues getting it to project the actual emoji. I've tried doing it through an image id (because it is overlapping another background API) as well as its own container. My current code looks like this:

```
function getEmojiApi() {
  var emojiApi = 'https://emojihub.yurace.pro/api/random/category/smileys-and-people'
  
  fetch(emojiApi)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response)
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    var emojiResults = document.getElementById('emoji');
    emojiResults.textContent = data.htmlCode
  })
    console.log("test2")
}
```

and the HTML for this code looks like this:

```
                    <div id="genResults">
                        <img id="imageResults">
                        <p id="emoji"></p>
                    </div>
```

The `imageResults` id is for a background generator that projects a background in a block on my page that I wanted to nest the emoji in the center of. I don't have any errors in my code and the API responds it just sends the actual htmlcode or unicode without the emoji itself. I've tried `.textContent` as well as .src (I'm still very new and learning). Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent`. Since the emoji are encoded in HTML, they need to be interpreted as HTML which is achieved with `.innerHMTL` . `.textContent` just displays text without special interpretation.